# how to programmatically create library feature with visual studio for sharepoint 2016, no template

Tags: document-library, visual-studio, feature

I need to create a library feature to deploy to farm. there is a list template but no library template. how do I create library feature, either programmatically from scratch or modifying list template if possible. using SharePoint server 2016 and visual studio 2022 and net framework 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

To create a library feature in SharePoint Server 2016, you can either create it programmatically from scratch or modify an existing list template. Here are the steps to create a library feature:

---

**Option 1**: Create a library feature programmatically from scratch

1. Open Visual Studio 2022 and create a new project using the "SharePoint - SharePoint 2016 - Empty Project" template.
2. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, select "Add" > "New Item" > "Empty Element".
3. In the new element's properties, set the "TemplateType" attribute to "101" to indicate that it's a document library.
4. Add any additional customizations to the library definition, such as columns, content types, or views, using the XML schema for the library definition.
5. Build and package the solution as a .wsp file.
6. Deploy the solution to the farm using PowerShell or Central Administration.

---

**Option 2**: Modify an existing list template to create a library feature

1. Open Visual Studio 2022 and create a new project using the "SharePoint - SharePoint 2016 - Import SharePoint Solution Package" template.
2. In the "Add Solution Package" dialog, browse to the .wsp file containing the list template you want to modify and select it.
3. In Solution Explorer, expand the solution package node and find the list template file (.stp) you want to modify.
4. Right-click the .stp file and select "Open With" > "XML (Text) Editor".
5. Locate the "Type" attribute in the "ListTemplate" element and change its value from "100" (generic list) to "101" (document library).
6. Save the modified list template file and close the XML editor.
7. Build and package the solution as a .wsp file.
8. Deploy the solution to the farm using PowerShell or Central Administration.

---

Note that modifying an existing list template can have unintended consequences, such as breaking existing lists based on that template, so it's recommended to test any modifications thoroughly in a development environment before deploying to production.

Comment: awesome, thank you! option 1 was what i was looking for.  much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to know that it did help! please mark this as an answer if it helped you. :)